# Could not find named location "@app" containerised node application

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, nginx

I have a containerised nodejs app on my server and I have a nginx webserver so it can use https that is supposed to redirect to the node app but I always get the error in the title and I have no clue why? My node app is showing as restarting though, which might be a problem, but again I don't know why it's restarting as it gives me nothing in the logs:

[image]

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        container_name: app
        restart: unless-stopped
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - app-network

    db:
        container_name: db
        image: mongo
        ports:
            - '27017:27017'

    webserver:
        image: nginx:mainline-alpine
        container_name: webserver
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - web-root:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
            - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
            - dhparam:/etc/ssl/certs
        depends_on:
            - app
        links:
            - app
        networks:
            - app-network

    certbot:
        image: certbot/certbot
        container_name: certbot
        volumes:
            - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
            - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
            - web-root:/var/www/html
        depends_on:
            - webserver
        command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email email@gmail.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal -d domain.com  -d www.domain.com 

    volumes:
        certbot-etc:
        certbot-var:
        web-root:
            driver: local
            driver_opts:
                type: none
                device: /home/root/app/views/
                o: bind
    dhparam:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: none
            device: /home/root/app/dhparam/
            o: bind

    networks:
        app-network:
            driver: bridge
```

And my nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
      allow all;
      root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.wasdstudios.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.wasdstudios.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location @nodejs {
            proxy_pass http://app:8080;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
            add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
            add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
            # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
            # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
    }

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
}
```

First part of my node file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const db = require('mongoose');

// Import routes
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');
const recoverRoute = require('./routes/recover');
const getUser = require('./routes/getUser');


// Connect to db
console.log(process.env.DB_CONNECT);
db.connect('mongodb://db:27017/app-mongo-database', { useNewUrlParser: true },  (err, client) => 
{ 
if(err){ 
    console.log(err); 
}
else{
    console.log("connected to db");
}
});

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.use('/auth/getUser', getUser);


// Route middlewares
app.use('/auth', authRoute);
app.use('/auth/recover', recoverRoute )

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server started'));
```

This is the log I get when i look into the app's containers log:

[image]

And when I go to my domain I get the obvious:

[image]

Update:

I do a docker-compose up -b -d command and this is the output ( npm start is running correctly):

[image]

It's now displaying this when I do a `docker-compose ps`

[image]

I'ts showing `npm start` now as it should, but it still does not work with the same error.

Comment: how does the start command in your package.json look like?

Comment: @MaximOrlov just the normal "start": "node app.js"

Comment: do u have a dockerignore file? ignoring your local node_modules? I just ur docker file and compose (only the app part) and it is working for me.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Looking at the wrong thing, I do not, but I don't have. node_modules folder at the moment for some reason. As if the RUN npm install command isn't being run in the Dockerfile?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty installed in manually, still the same

Comment: can you check your dockerfile if your CMD is indeed CMD ["npm", "start"]? cause I can see in the `docker-compose ps` it is running `npm a...`

Comment: @AritraChakraborty yes, it definitely is doing that command

Comment: You can `docker exec -it <containerid> /bin/sh` and check the Dockerfile INSIDE that.. I have a feeling the either you are using another Dockerfile or the curernt dockerfile is somhow changed.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I get Error response from daemon: Container 0b711b1cb63a6283428c1eddfb1d13ca5f5b5c7539a64165f5fc911ed26d4d0f is restarting, wait until the container is running

Comment: Like @Nathan said, your start command is `npm a ...` as you can see from `docker compose ps`. Try running `docker compose up --build` if you're confident your Dockerfile has `CMD ["npm", "start"]`. This will force a rebuild of your images.

Comment: @MaximOrlov see the bottom of my question, I added the output of that command.

Comment: So, now the app starts, But one of the problem in ur docker compose file is, your app should depend on db, so that it can connect to db while starting up. Now check your nginx logs.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Yeah, I realised that, I added the depends_on on the app service and I get this error in the app containers log file: `[MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db db:27017` even though it worked before adding nginx, so I'm assuming ports have been blocked?

Comment: maybe in your js file change `db:27017` with `127.0.0.1:27017` and check. But it should work as is

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I get a different error `MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I fixed the problem with the db not being able to connect to the app I just made the app use the same network as the db/webserver since they were using different ones, but, I still get the error `Could not find named location “@app” containerised node application`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I had to add the add the apps-network into my db service file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        container_name: app
        restart: unless-stopped
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
        - db
    networks:
        - app-network

db:
    container_name: db
    image: mongo
    ports:
        - '27017:27017'
    networks:          ////////// <<<<< here
        - app-network
```

and update my `nginx.conf` file to this, I made an error and my try files uri wasd called app, not nodejs.:

```
        location / {
        try_files $uri @app;   ///// <<<<< this should be nodejs not 'app'
    }

    location @nodejs {. /// <<<<< as long as it's the same as this name 
            proxy_pass http://app:8080;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
            add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
            add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    }
```

You can compare code, if needed, with my question to see if you fall in the same error as me.